# How to blank column value when previous value is the same

Tags: cakephp

As a result from a group find, I get something like

```
id   name                               date            project
2898 Noemi Araceli Farre Gutierrez      2012-07-23      mr12249-Northgate Field  
2898 Noemi Araceli Farre Gutierrez      2012-07-24      mr12251-Marketon Field  
2898 Noemi Araceli Farre Gutierrez      2012-07-25      mr12251-Marketon Field  
2898 Noemi Araceli Farre Gutierrez      2012-07-26      mr12249-Northgate Field 
3047 Mauricio Javier García             2012-07-22      mr12249-Northgate Field  
3047 Mauricio Javier García             2012-07-23      mr12251-Marketon Field  
3047 Mauricio Javier García             2012-07-26      mr12251-Marketon Field
```

In my view i need to avoid repeating the id and name, and show like:

```
id   name                               date            project
2898 Noemi Araceli Farre Gutierrez      2012-07-23      mr12249-Northgate Field  
                                        2012-07-24      mr12251-Marketon Field  
                                        2012-07-25      mr12251-Marketon Field  
                                        2012-07-26      mr12249-Northgate Field 
3047 Mauricio Javier García             2012-07-22      mr12249-Northgate Field  
                                        2012-07-23      mr12251-Marketon Field  
                                        2012-07-26      mr12251-Marketon Field
```

I could do it by comparing the current and previous value during the foreach loop in the view, but it seems to me there's got to be a better, cake way.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "better cake way" for this. It's a simple PHP logic.

```
$currentName = null;
foreach ($results as $row) {
    if ($row['name'] != $currentName) {
        $currentName = $row['name'];
        echo $currentName;
    }
    else {
        // Do not display anything
        // you may need to echo some tab characters or something to keep
        // the table formatted
    }
}
```